# probability function of wrapped distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Good day,

i would like to ask anybody for help. I am working on wrapped distributions, but i am kind of stuck on one problem. I cant see, why if you are defining the probability function of particular example of wrapped distribution, which has probability concentrated on points x=2pik/m, why there is r + km in infinite sum then. I am adding the picture from the book iam reading right now.

Thanks for any help.
Have a nice day to all.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in your book. It should be clear that
$$P(x_w = \theta) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty P(x=\theta+2\pi k)$$
Rephrasing this in terms of probability density functions, 
$$
p(\theta) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty  p(\theta+2\pi k)
$$
Letting $\theta=2\pi r/m$, 
$$
p(2\pi r/m) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty  p(2\pi(r/m+k))
$$
so a factor of $2\pi$ is missing from the right hand side of the book's last equation.

Comment: I think so as well, and the same is clear to me too, but i found the same result in many other books (which have this book in references) but i am still not sure about it. But thanks anyways for your help.

Comment: Most likely when they say p(k), they don't mean the probability x equals k, but rather the probability that x equals the $k^{th}$ value in its support. @stanly